# React-Redux Error: undefined is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have use React-Redux. When I get data from store and use useSelector hook. this error occur and say '**undefined is not a function**'. I have found on internet but no answer I haven't found. Please help me. I am stuck in this error. Thank you

Comment: Can you show a little bit of your code?

Comment: No one here, or anywhere, can help diagnose or debug code that they can't see very well. Please update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the relevant code you are having an issue using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not supply any code, I could only give several possible causes for this kind of error.

1. Check your spellings. Getting undefined is because you are referencing a json key that does not exist.
2. Check if you have initialized your state in your reducer.

You can debug both 1 and 2 using the following method:

```
const {param1, param2} = useSelector(state => {
                                               console.log(state)
                                               return state.yourReducer
                                               });
```